# Speed up many string searches in the same large file?

Tags: python, linux, sorting, search, grep

I've got about 200GB of data that I'm trying to search inside for various strings (primarily using grep or python regexes). Right now, each time I come up with a new string it takes quite a long time to grep all of these files to see if there are any matches. Are there any clever algorithms or linux utilities that might help index / store sorted metadata about the contents these files so that I can do some heavy computational work up front and then search more quickly in the future?

Comment: A database with full-text search capabilities would be one option.

Comment: Install Elasticsearch or Solr and upload your data